# using jquery validate but prevent the form submit

Tags: jquery

the form is still submitted. if i want to use your code and add a step.that is if show the red text then preventing the form to submit?how do i do? thank you.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    if (!$("#edit-name").val() || !$("#edit-email").val() || !$("#edit-comment-body").val())
    {
        $("#edit-submit").click(function()
        {
            $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的名字</span>');
            $('#edit-mail').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的邮箱</span>');
            $('#edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">请填写内容</span>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the .click(function()) give it a parameter e

```
    $("#edit-submit").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的名字</span>');
        $('#edit-mail').after('<span style="color:red;">请输入你的邮箱</span>');
        $('#edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">请填写内容</span>');
    });
```

Comment: many thanks. why i using submit()function. the js code can't work. there still have a question.after i click the button, if i click again. the red text will add once again. how to prevent it. thank you.

Comment: what's the  parameter e meaning?

Comment: e is the event parameter. Can you elaborate on your other question a bit? I don't quite follow.

Answer (score 2):

validate the fields inside submit event like:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){
      if ($("#edit-name").val()=='' || $("#edit-email").val()=='' || $("#edit-comment-body").val()==''){
        $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;">è¯·è¾“å…¥ä½ çš„åå­—</span>');
        $('#edit-mail').after('<span style="color:red;">è¯·è¾“å…¥ä½ çš„é‚®ç®±</span>');
        $('#edit-comment-body label span').append('<span style="color:red;">è¯·å¡«å†™å†…å®¹</span>');

        return false; // to stop form submission in any way
```

}
    });

Comment: here still have a question.after i click the button, if i click again. the red text will add once again. how to prevent it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you hook an event listener to the submit event of the form, from there you can return false.

```
$("form#foo").submit(function(){
    // validate
    return false;
});
```